# I heard this word/compound in an anime and I can't find a single example of it online, am I understanding it correctly? (参加出）

Tags: meaning, translation, kanji, anime, transcription

During an exchange in which a character asks another to participate in an event, the other character replies　さんかで。(I'm writing it in hiragana 'cause I'm still not sure of the kanjis.) Context-wise the only possible meaning for that phrase considering the reactions of the characters is "I'm not participating", and I checked the subs to be sure and that's what they went with as well. Going with that interpretation, the only way I could make sense of it is if it was written as 参加出, but I can't find an example of it online, and that worries me. I also tried looking for it in plain hiragana, I tried looking up synonyms and quasi-synonyms of　参加しない, and nothing. Is this normal?

This character doesn't even have weird speaking patterns or anything, they're just kind of aloof, so I can't just mark this up as "anime shenanigans" and get on with my life. I haven't learned a language like Japanese before, so it makes me really anxious that I can encounter phrases/words like this and not be able to find an example for them online...

Transcript of the conversation, just in case:

> Character A: そうとなったら、早速セッチングするで！
> **Character B: さんかで**
> Character A: 何でや？来いや！
> Character B: (explains why they can't go/participate)

(Anime is Sakura Card Captor Clear Card, ep07)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I listened to the clip and I hear "不参加で" (short for "不参加でお願いします").